# Is $V= W\oplus W^{\perp}$ always?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is $V= W\oplus W^{\perp}$ always?
> Here, $W$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$.

I think this holds if $V$ is finite-dimensional, but what if it is not? Could someone help me prove $V= W\oplus W^{\perp}$ in the **infinite-dimensional** case, or produce a counterexample? I'm really not sure where to start.

The thing is, I am not able to see how moving from finite dimensions to infinite dimensions changes anything. Shouldn't it be the case that a vector lies in $W$ or $W^\perp$? **Where else can it lie?**

P.S.
*This isn't part of a homework exercise or something, it just came to my mind. I'm taking a class in Linear Algebra right now that deals mostly with finite-dimensional vector spaces only, so I don't know where to start in this case.*

Comment: An answer that is easy to digest for an undergraduate who is exposed only to finite-dimensional vector spaces would be nice.

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case you have to assume that $W$ is a closed subspace.

Comment: You can see some discussion on this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636517/is-it-true-that-the-whole-space-is-the-direct-sum-of-a-subspace-and-its-orthogon)

Comment: And [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922939/characterization-of-hilbert-spaces-using-orthogonal-decomposition) for a more recent answer

Comment: Also related: [How could I find a non-closed linear subspace $X$ of $l^{2}$, such that $ l^{2} \ne X + X^{\perp}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493642)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to define orthogonal complements we need $V$ to be an [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), not just a vector space. Then it is generally false that $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ if $V$ is an infinite-dimensional inner product space. A standard counterexample is to take $V$ to be the [$\ell^2$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces) of sequences

$$\ell^2(\mathbb{N}) = \{ a_n \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 < \infty \}$$

equipped with the inner product $\langle a, b \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$, and to take $W$ to be the subspace consisting of sequences with finite support (sequences such that $a_n = 0$ for sufficiently large $n$). It's a nice exercise to check that $W^{\perp} = 0$, so $W \oplus W^{\perp} = W$ is strictly smaller than $V$, and does not contain e.g. the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

The standard fix is to assume that $V$ is a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) (which is true here) and that $W$ is a [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) subspace (which is not true here); then the statement is true. $V$ being a Hilbert space and $W$ being closed allows you to define the [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) of an element of $V$ onto $W$ which is what makes the proof work; you can check in the above example that the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ does not admit an orthogonal projection onto $W$.

In a bit more detail, one way to define the orthogonal projection which works in finite dimensions is to take the closest vector in $W$, and another is to use an orthonormal basis of $W$ and define the orthonormal projection as a certain sum of projections onto the basis; both approaches generally fail in infinite dimensions because a limit you need to exist doesn't always exist, unless $V$ is Hilbert and $W$ is closed.

> Shouldn't it be the case that a vector lies in $W$ or $W^\perp$?

Be careful; this is not what a direct sum means. A direct sum means that a vector decomposes into a component in $W$ and a component in $W^{\perp}$, not that it lies in either $W$ or $W^{\perp}$.

Comment: let V be infinite dimensional inner product space. and W is a finite dimensional subspace .then by Grahm Schmidt process we have ONB of W .now using sum of projection we have V as a direct sum of W and its OC. is my approach right?